# JSON path reading

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have such question:
In file i have multiple json lines like this

```
{"id":1,"my_struct":{"other_id":1,"text":"HelloWorld0"}}
{"id":2,"my_struct":{"other_id":12,"text":"HelloWorld1"}}
{"id":3,"my_struct":{"other_id":123,"text":"HelloWorld2"}}
```

I try to get data with JSON Path query:

```
&.id
```

and i get empty line.
But if i use same JSON Path query on file only with one line

```
{"id":1,"my_struct":{"other_id":1,"text":HelloWorld0}}
```

I get proper result: 1
What I'm doing wrong? How can I get all id's?

Comment: That file is not valid JSON. You'd have to specify which line to use.

Comment: Is it possible to iterate on all JSON lines?

Comment: Er, what does ‘*JSON line*’ mean, exactly? If each line is valid JSON, then yes, it's possible to iterate over the lines, with your favourite tool for such tasks.

Comment: Yes. Each line is valid JSON. Can you tell me how can I iterate over each line in file?

Comment: I *could* tell you how to do it with certain tools. I *can't* tell you how to do it with whatever you're using, since you've neglected to tell us what it is.

Comment: I'm using Talend Open studio. with succ Loop Jsonpath query: "$.bills.bill.line[*]"

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, it is incorrect JSON format. You can actually validate the JSON or generate JSON in this online tool : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Please read on the examples in here for more details for JsonPath : https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#user-content-path-examples

To make your JSON valid, it should be in this format:

```
[
  {"id":1,"my_struct":{"other_id":1,"text": "HelloWorld0 Value"}},
  {"id":2,"my_struct":{"other_id":12,"text": "HelloWorld1 Value"}},
  {"id":3,"my_struct":{"other_id":123,"text": "HelloWorld2 Value"}}
]
```

To answer your question on how to get all ids, it will be using `"$.[*].id"`.

Comment: Damn. You are right.  When I surrounded this all with [] and added commas   "$.[*].id" began to work. Is it somehow possible to read file without rewriting it(without adding [, ] and , ) it?

Comment: @UNIm95  Short answer is yes, it is possible. You just need to read the JSON object per line from your file and create the correct format programmatically by pushing the strings in an array and then convert. It is important to still add the brackets and commas in your JSON structure as it is what JSON is made of.